# Re-using a Google docs project without publishing it

Tags: google-apps-script

I am not ready to publish a project I am working on. It is an Apps Script project within the Google docs container. However, I want to use it on multiple docs that I share with other people. The issue is that it has a menu, dialog and a sidebar. 
It does not appear that referencing it as a library helps. onOpen() does not get called.

The only way I have found to be able to share the project with other people is to take a copy of the development document, clear out the contents and then share it. That means I am creating a copy of the project and changes in the original will not appear in the copies.

Is that the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the only way is to share the original/copy of that document.

This shares the Apps Script project with the Google Doc and the changes in the Apps Script project reflects to the other shared users, but the updates in the Google Doc shared will not be updated to the other users.

You can also try this [option](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/collaborating) by sharing them as a Container-bound projects

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar thing and according to my research about this, the best solution to share is publishing your script as an add-on. That requires a one-time developer fee of $5 but that will be easier for you. Make sure you publish it privately if you want to share it with only a set of people.

Hope this solves your problem!